# How to connect to mongodb from docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker

How to connect to mongodb from docker and to see all collections?

I have installed and launched this [docker image](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/master/kafka-docker-example/)

How to connect and to make insert, update?

Comment: Well, MongoDB has a default port, so you could try with that.

Comment: Outside docker or in docker? How to do that?

Comment: I guess outside.  The connection string should be something like `mongodb://127.0.0.1/dbname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your container has port forwarded, like "27017:27017" then you can connect it with any mongo client sitting on your machine.

Example: mongo -u  -p  127.0.0.1/